lldb printing ipv6 address in textual form
While debugging some library called c-ares which send multiple dns requests for efficiency. I was trying to verify that it properly loaded the correct dns server by printing the network binary representation of its ipv6 address in textual form. Here's the crude data :
(lldb) p server->addr.addr.addr6._S6_un._S6_u8
(unsigned char[16]) "*\U00000006\xc7\U00000001\xff\xff\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\U00000001"

I've used inet_ntop is it should handle both types (ipv4 and ipv6) but i get all zeros :
(lldb) p (char*)inet_ntop(server->addr.addr.addr6._S6_un._S6_u8)
(char *) 0x0000000000000000

Another lldb macro I've found is inet_ntoa which works perfect but it only fits for ipv4, and i couldn't find ipv6 equivalent.
Any idea how to print it properly ? right now my workaround is to copy the data to python and use socket.inet_ntop
Thanks !

inet_ntop expects 4 arguments.

I guess that besides the C version, inet_ntop also has an equivalent macro in lldb, and I wonder why it return 0 instead of the actual string which represent the ipv6 address. but if i'm wrong, and I need to provide the 4 arguments, so I can it be done from the debugger prompt ?

You can write a macro inet_ntop for lldb.

The x/16xb command can get you pretty close. x -s1 -fx -c16 -l 16 is the native LLDB equivalent for that. If you want to automate that you can use Python type summaries.

@Botje, maybe you can make an answer from your comment, so i can rate it. thanks
